# TikZ positioning: align nodes along bottom edge

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,physics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1, draw, anchor=south},auto]
    \node (LMA) [stack=1,label=below:{\texttt{LM(A)}}] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (PUM1) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{PuM()}},right=of LMA] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{A}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (MMB) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{MM(B)}},right=of PUM1] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{AB}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (MMC) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{MM(C)}},right=of MMB] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{ABC}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (LMD) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{LM(D)}},right=of MMC] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (PUM2) [stack=3,label=below:{\texttt{PuM()}},right=of LMD] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{three}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (MME) [stack=3,label=below:{\texttt{MM(E)}},right=of PUM2] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{DE}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{three}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (MMF) [stack=3,label=below:{\texttt{MM(F)}},right=of MME] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{DEF}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{three}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which generates the following:

[image]

How might I change it such that all the stacks are aligned along their *bottom* edges to show the matrix stacks growing (I have already tried this with `anchor=south`, but clearly that doesn't work), with the labels immediately below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Position the two nodes that differ in size from the previous one with the options

```
right=of LMA.south east,anchor=south west
right=of LMD.south east,anchor=south west
```

respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,physics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1, draw, anchor=south},auto]
    \node (LMA) [stack=1,label=below:{\texttt{LM(A)}}] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (PUM1) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{PuM()}},right=of LMA.south east,anchor=south west] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{A}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (MMB) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{MM(B)}},right=of PUM1] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{AB}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (MMC) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{MM(C)}},right=of MMB] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{ABC}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (LMD) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{LM(D)}},right=of MMC] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (PUM2) [stack=3,label=below:{\texttt{PuM()}},right=of LMD.south east,anchor=south west] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{three}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (MME) [stack=3,label=below:{\texttt{MM(E)}},right=of PUM2] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{DE}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{three}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (MMF) [stack=3,label=below:{\texttt{MM(F)}},right=of MME] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{DEF}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{three}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Adaptations

- (I reduced the MWE a little bit)
- Use `anchor=south west` for all nodes (the anchor is only considered, if you give a position, e.g. `at (x, y)` or a position of a node (see [gernots answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617802/123129)), not a node)
- Set position to `south east` of the last node plus an offset, defined in `dist`.

##### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,physics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1, draw, anchor=south west},
    auto,
    dist/.style={xshift=10mm}
    ]
    
    \node (LMA) [stack=1,label=below:{\texttt{LM(A)}}] {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (PUM1) [stack=2,label=below:{\texttt{PuM()}}] at ([dist] LMA.south east) {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{A}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
    \node (PUM2) [stack=3,label=below:{\texttt{PuM()}}] at ([dist] PUM1.south east) {
        \nodepart{one}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{two}\(\vb*{D}\)
        \nodepart{three}\(\vb*{A}\)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: Much obliged. Is there no way to use the `right=of` syntax, then? I found it really convenient.

Comment: Yes, gernot gave an answer to that. I learned something :)